# Is a non stratified survey sample 70,000 people sufficient to make conclusions about a population of 12 million people?

Tags: survey, sample, population

Is a survey with a sample size of 70,000 people sufficient to make conclusions about a population of 12 million people when there is no way to ensure that the sample is stratified sample where the proportion of each type of category of respondents in the population is maintained in the sample?

If not, what is the minimum recommendation for surveying in such a scenario.

Comment: a simple random sample of only a few thousand would likely be enough to draw very accurate estimates.  on the other hand, if you didn't select survey respondents randomly and also don't know how your sample differs from your population, there isn't really a minimum number that will correct the bias of a convenience sample